# Django model inheritance based on atribute value?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Sorry, but I'm starting with programming Django and I need help.

I need a class (inheritance) when the parent attribute is true, and thus when to seek the child class, bring all that hold this attribute to true.

See the code:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

class People(Person):
    registration_number = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1)

class Company(Person):
    registration_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    foundation_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["nome"]

class Customer(Person):
    # I want to consider all Person object with customer=True
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to filter your Person query like so:

```
customers = Person.objects.filter(customer=True)
```

You don't need another class